# Converting String from EditText to Integer

Tags: java, android

***Please help me my application is getting Crashed I don't know what wrong I am doing***  I Think error is in converting String from EditText into Integer.

```
package com.example.talha.int_test;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText e1;
TextView t1;
Button b1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    final int a = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            t1.setText("Value in A: "+a);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: every time i run it its getting crashed

Comment: Are you able find anything in logcat..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a `NumberFormatException` because you are trying to parse an empty `String` at the start of `onCreate`. In order to fix this move your `parseInt` into the click listener of `b1` like this

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int a = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
        t1.setText("Value in A: "+a);
    }
});
```

Keep in mind that your `EditText` should probably have `inputType="number"` or the user can put anything into it. Then you have to use `try-catch` to avoid possible app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
 e1.getText().tostring it returns "" which is empty string hence you can't convert it to integer so make sure  it is not empty 

  String x=e1.getText.toString();
  If(!x.isEmpty() &&  x.length()>1){
 //Now parse your string here
  final int a= Integer.parseInt(x);
```

}